# DOM - Parsing text from a node

Tags: android, xml, dom, domparser

According to [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), I think I have done this right... or at least so I think.

I want to parse this:

```
<Title>Bananas</Title>
```

Here is some code.

```
node1.getNodeName();                  // returns "Title"   *correct*
node2 = node1.getNextSibling();
node2.getNodeName();                  // returns "#text"   *correct*
node2.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE // returns true      *correct*
node2.getNodeValue();                 // returns ""        *should return "Bananas"*
```

According to the documentation, shouldn't the call to **getNodeValue()** on a Text Node return its text value?

Comment: On a very related note, have you seen Simple XML? It works on all Android versions: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Try this

node2.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing the text after the `</title>` You probably want something like `node1.getFirstChild()`

Use this line instead

```
node2 = node1.getFirstChild();
```

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you.  I wonder why getNextSibling() was saying it was a TextNode... Weird.

Comment: Its likely that there is a hidden text field after your </title> tag which the XML parser was looking at and not ignoring